# My sql -u root can't connect from within MAMP

Tags: mysql, mamp, wordpress

I'm running a local wordpress install through MAMP, and I'm trying to access a mysql db that I can access in the shell (mac terminal) with mysql -u root. I'm trying to connect to the db using the a new instance of the wpdb object in a wordpress template file, and I'm getting a WordPress database error: [Unknown database 'DB_NAME'].

If I try to connect to one of the other db's installed through a mamp wordpress install, it knows about them. I'm trying to understand how MAMP defines its own root, and how I can access the db that I can call in the shell from my wordpress install within MAMP. I think that I may have to set a symlink somewhere in the MAMP install, but I'm not sure. This db is too big to access through phpmyadmin, so I would like to continue to access it through the terminal.

If anyone has found a workaround for this, I'd love to hear about it.

I found this entry:
[Can't diagnose my MySQL root user problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424240/cant-diagnose-my-mysql-root-user-problem)
which sheds some light on my issue, but it doesn't solve it. I don't want to make it harder to access my root user db's through other apps.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new user through phpmyadmin / shell and try with that rather than using root with no password.